# Match certain parts of a mesh to the body?

Tags: vertex-groups

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to make Knight tassets, as show in the second pic. So I need the cream colored part of my mesh to stay to the color coded bone, the green colored part to the green bone and so forth so that the entire thing doesn't look so stiff when it moves. Been fiddling with it for like an hour and still can't figure it out. I took like a 2 week break from Blender and I think I sorta braindumped everything,

Any help? I've made vertex groups for each part of the mesh but can't figure out what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the appropriate parts of the mesh to the appropriate bones like you would normally. Use the weight paint tool, or vertex grouping.

For those side plates I would definitely recommend assigning them their own bones if they are not strapped into the leg, and would, for instance, hang downward if the character leaned to one side.

Comment: I tried to assign the appropriate parts of the mesh to the bones, but the issue is the whole mesh is a child to the spine. And when I remove the child of constraint and create those vertex groups I don't understand how to assign them to the bone. Would I get the same results by just separating the tassets by the bones and assigning each one to said bones? If that makes sense.

Comment: The entire mesh shouldn't be a child of the 'spine'. You should an an armature modifier to your mesh, and pass the bone object in a the parameter to modifier. Then you should be able to go into vertex paint mode and select the bones, and see a green, red, yellow and blue color coding of the weight of the bones on each vertex. The little plates on the side should have their own bones starting at the top plate (because the other child plates connect to that), and there should be child bones coming from that top bone for each of the individual plates if they are not all tethered to the leg.